# Unable to write multiple JSON records using push in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a huge JSON file of around 3 GB which contains multiple JSON records (each record per line) as shown below:

```
{"deviceId":"52b336d46d01bde9","dow":"Thursday","downloadFlag":"N"}
{"deviceId":"8B0FCD5F-B62A-5351-0000-000000000000","dow":"Thursday"}
{"deviceId":"969D8075-9C9B-DE14-0000-000000000000","dow":"jeudi","downloadFlag":"Y"}
```

I have to write these JSON records in Firebase Realtime DB and I am trying to achieve it through Python using the below mentioned code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

from firebase_admin import db
import json

cred = credentials.Certificate('./test.json')
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'databaseURL' : 'https://test.firebaseio.com/'})

user_activities_sample = db.reference("userActivities")

new_post_ref = user_activities_sample.push()

f = open("test_save.json", "r")

for line in f.readlines():
    data = json.loads(line)
    print data
    new_post_ref.set(data)
```

Issue is that only the last record in the JSON file is getting written to the Database.
Is there anything incorrect in my code or my understanding of push is wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What actually your code doing is, it is overwriting the values every time you use the `set()` method.

Because `new_post_ref = user_activities_sample.push()` this line stores a `Database Reference` in the variable `new_post_ref` (which will remain the same unless you change that), and you are `set()`ing every time on that `ref` without changing that. That's why `firebase` is overwriting the value at key `new_post_ref` in the database, as a result, this will save only the last `set()`ed value.

So, to correct this behavior you've to `push()` everytime you `set()` a new value in the database, like so:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

from firebase_admin import db
import json

cred = credentials.Certificate('./test.json')
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'databaseURL' : 'https://test.firebaseio.com/'})

user_activities_sample = db.reference("userActivities")

f = open("test_save.json", "r")

for line in f.readlines():
    data = json.loads(line)
    print data
    user_activities_sample.push().set(data) # now there will be new ref everytime you add new value to database
```

In this way, your problem will be eradicated.